# date time conversion to specific format

Tags: java, datetime, date, datetime-format

I have a class file where the date field has value like "1329242400". This value in UI is represented as "0 day 00:02:56". 
I tried below but I get date in 1970's.

```
String attr = "1329242400";
Date cDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(attr));
```

Output is "Fri Jan 16 04:16:55 EST 1970"

Tried below,

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(cDate);
XMLGregorianCalendar dDt = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
```

Output is "1970-01-16T04:16:55.200-05:00"

What other conversion method should I do to get "0 day 00:02:56" or like "Tue Feb 14 00:02:56 EST 2011"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor expects the time stamp to be in milliseconds, so you're off by 3 orders of magnitude:

```
Date cDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(attr) * 1000);
                                           ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(cDate);
XMLGregorianCalendar dDt = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("E MM dd hh:mm:ss z");
sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

Your string, `"1329242400"` is the number of seconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT` (or UTC). You can convert it into an `Instant` using [`Instant#ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) which represents an instantaneous point on the timeline. It is independent of timezone (i.e. has a timezone offset of `00:00` hours, represented with `Z` in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards).

You can convert `Instant` to a `ZonedDateTime` by applying the applicable `ZoneId`.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(Long.parseLong("1329242400"));
        System.out.println(instant);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2012-02-14T18:00:00Z
2012-02-14T13:00-05:00[America/New_York]
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>